# Is it possible in principle (but not in practice) to recursively factor away the Riemann zeta zeros as they are computed?

Tags: polynomials, riemann-zeta-function, differential-operators, riemann-hypothesis, rootfinding

Let: $$f_0(x)=\frac{\zeta (x)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)}$$ and let the seed point be: $$s=\sqrt{-1}$$
which is the input into the limit:
$$\rho_1=s+\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{f_0\left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{1}{n}+s\right)}}{\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{f_0\left(\frac{k}{n}+s\right)}}\right)^{-1}$$
Then for the truncated limit at $n=170$ we seem to numerically get the first Riemann zeta zero:

$\rho_1 \approx $ `0.500000000809315424 + 14.134725141999078436 I`

Now factor away the first zeta zero pair $\rho _{+j}$ and $\rho _{-j}$ from $f_0(x)$ by dividing with the product: $$\prod _{j=1}^m (x-\rho _j) (x-\rho _{-j})$$
where $m=1$,
that is:

$$f_m(\text{x}) = \frac{\zeta (x)}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right) \prod\limits_{j=1}^{m} (x-\rho _j) (x-\rho _{-j})}$$

and with $s=\sqrt{-1}$ then feed $f_m (x)$ into the binomial sum limit:

$$\rho_{m+1}=s+\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{f_m\left(\frac{k}{n}-\frac{1}{n}+s\right)}}{\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{f_m\left(\frac{k}{n}+s\right)}}\right)^{-1}$$

which again for the truncated limit at $n=170$ seems to numerically give the first, second, third, fourth, fifth... Riemann zeta zero:

$m = 0$:
$\rho_1 \approx $ `0.500000000809315424 + 14.134725141999078436 I`
$m = 1$:
$\rho_2 \approx $ `0.500003240725315219 + 21.022038108654950356 I`
$m = 2$:
$\rho_3 \approx $ `0.500044971947739555 + 25.010893102992784503 I`
$m = 3$:
$\rho_4 \approx $ `0.500605374548171145 + 30.424287649143723384 I`
$m = 4$:
$\rho_5 \approx $ `0.500830274970246344 + 32.936917518238269262 I`
and so on with $m \rightarrow \infty$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$.

> Is it then possible in principle (but not in practice) to recursively
> factor away the Riemann zeta zeros as they are computed? Or will this pattern of consecutive zeros eventually fail? Is the Lehmer pair a problem?

The Mathematica program by which the approximations of zeros were computed:

```
(*Mathematica start, takes a minute to run*)
Clear[f, s, X, n, k, x, m];
m = 0; (* try setting: m = 0, m = 1, m = 2, m = 3, m = 4,... *)
f[x_] := Zeta[x]/Sin[Pi*x/2]/
   Product[(x - ZetaZero[j])*(x - ZetaZero[-j]), {j, 1, m}];
(* f[x_]:= x^2-2 *)
s = I;
n = 170;
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500}, 
 X = N[(1/(1 - 
        Sum[((-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1])/
           f[k/n + s - 1/n], {k, 1, n}]/
         Sum[((-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1])/f[k/n + s], {k, 1, 
           n}]) + s), 20]]
f[X]
(*end*)
```

$f(x)$ can probably be any polynomial, and the binomial sum ratio comes from a tweaked version of the ratio of higher order derivatives of a function, with the formula "left unevaluated" until the desired highest order of the derivatives is chosen. I have the partial derivation somewhere on Mathematics stack exchange.